# ember-responsive, {{media}} in template.hbs is undefined if I use media: Ember.inject.service() in route. Why?

Tags: css, ember.js, responsive-design, ember-cli

I'm using https://github.com/freshbooks/ember-responsive.

`{{media}}` in **templates/route.hbs** is undefined if I use `media: Ember.inject.service()` in **routes/route.js**.

If instead I recreate the default **initializers/responsive.js** file everything works.

In route it works also with service inject only using this code in

```
activate() {
  console.log(this.get('media.isMobile'));
}
```

it logs true or false accordingly.

But in **template.hbs** this code: `{{log media}`} or `{{log media.classNames}}` or

```
{{#if media.isDesktop}}
  Desktop view!
{{/if}}
```

is always undefined or shows nothing until I use initializer instead of just inject service in this route only.

**Why?**

Comment: that did not make sense to me; can you share a dummy project over github or just a mock twiddle.

Comment: I can't now. You can try with a new simply project with ember-cli anyway.

Comment: I have created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6eeb8f8c600c5be7f016abddd42119ad?openFiles=templates.index.hbs%2C) and it is working fine. Check it out.

Comment: See @Gokul solved your problem; you were trying to display a property of route within template. You cannot do that; you need to inject the service to the controller. That was your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template will pull the properties only via the controller. If you want any property that needs to be displayed or used in the template, then you have to mention that property in controller file (`controllers/route.js` in your case). Try something like,

`media: Ember.inject.service()` in your controller and you can use the `media` service in the template. With respect to the initializer, You might have injected into the controller too using, `application.inject('controller', 'media', 'service:media');` that is why media service may be accessible in that case.

Comment: good catch. he was trying to access route property from template. I missed that initially.